# Working with multiple AWS keys in Hadoop environment

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3

What's the workaround for having multiple AWS keys in Hadoop environment? My hadoop jobs will require access to two different S3 buckets (two different keys). Tried with "credential" provider but looks like it's pretty limited. It stores all keys in lower case, as a result I cannot use "s3a" for one job and "s3n" for other job. For example: for s3a, it looks for:

```
fs.s3a.access.key
fs.s3a.secret.key
```

And for s3n:

```
fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId
fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey
```

But if I create provider with "fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", it stores as "fs.s3n.awsaccesskeyid", as a result, during runtime it fails to load the expected key.

As a workaround, I tried to generate two different credential providers and pass as:

```
--Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=key1,key2
```

But it didn't work togher as both of the keys have fs.s3a.access.key & fs.s3a.secrety.key pair.

I don't want to pass access and secret key using -D option as it's visible. Is there any better way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Why don't you have a single set of IAM credentials that allows access to both buckets?

Comment: Yeah, even if it's cross account you should be able to create a policy that grants access to both buckets from the account that has access to them both.  And if you're running this on EC2, use the ec2 instance profile to specify both credentials to the instance and its access policies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgrade to Hadoop 2.8 you can use the [per-bucket configurations](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Configurations_different_S3_buckets) to address this problem. Everything in fs.s3a.bucket.$BUCKETNAME is patched into the config for the FS instance for that bucket, overriding any other configs

`fs.s3a.bucket.engineering.access.key=AAID..
fs.s3a.bucket.logs.access.key=AB14...`

We use this a lot for talking to buckets in different regions, encryption, other things. Works well, so far. Though [I would say that](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13336).

Special exception: if you encrypt credential secrets in JCECKS files. The docs cover this.